# Firestore Data Structure get items from friends and friends of friends

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, data-modeling

I’m confronted with a problem I just really can’t find a good solution for. I am using Firebase Firestore a NoSQL database. I am trying to get all uploads from friends and friends of friends which the user is allowed to see. The allowance is determined by whether the uploader chose the item to be visible to friends or friends of friends or a custom group of users.

So far, I tried to set the security rules to read only if the requester is in the forUsers array of the item. Turns out the security rules aren’t made for that kind of query...

Another option would be a root collection of users and a root collection of items. Each item is referenced in a subcollection called item_refs of all the friends of the uploader.
With this setup to get the data for the feed 3 Queries would need to be fetched:

1. Get all of the current users item_refs
2. Get all item_refs from friends which are for friends of friends or for everyone.
3. get all items for everybody.

This is especially a bad setup for querying the uploads by distance.

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: I found an [example](https://html.developreference.com/article/12479877/Firebase+Firestore%2C+query+a+users+friend's+posts) regarding querying a user's friends posts, where the developer makes use of Cloud Functions, which you might find useful, as Cloud Function is not bound by security rules.

Comment: Sadly those batch writes would add up to large costs since firestore is billed by read and writes. :/